# Haskell - Replace substring in a string using recursion(functions take and drop are not allowed in my case)

Tags: string, haskell, recursion

I need to Replace one line in the sentence with another for example “qwer sder” “er” “ol”  “qwol sdol”.
I managed to do something similar replacing one char with another

```
replace :: Char -> Char -> String -> String
replace _ _ "" = ""
replace x y (c:cs) = if c == x then y : replace x y cs else c : replace x y cs
```

But have no idea how to do that with strings (not chars).

Comment: Hint: take a look as [**`isPrefixOf :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf).

Answer (score 0):

A naive algorithm can make use of the [**`isPrefixOf :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf) function to check if we should replace that element.

Such function thus looks like:

```
replaceStr :: String -> String -> String -> String
replaceStr needle replacement = go
    where go "" = ""
          go xs@(x:xt)
              | isPrefixOf needle xs = …  -- (1)
              | otherwise = …  -- (2)
          nn = length needle
```

where I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise. In case the `needle` is a prefix of `xs`, one should drop `nn` characters from the string `xs` and replace these with the `replacement` and then recurse on the rest of the string (1). In case the `needle` is *not* a prefix of `xs`, then we yield `x` and recurse on the tail `xt` (2).

This algorithm can take quadratic time: if the needle is for example *n* characters `'A'` and the "haystack" is *m* characters `'A'`, then it will take *O(m×n)* time.

One can work with the [*Knuth-Morris-Pratt* algorithm [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) to perform search in linear time.

Comment: Sorry for bothering but i don't know how to do what you suggest without using drop func. And i can't use it. Is there some other way?

Comment: @BohdanChornopolskyi: then you can implement your own `drop` function. You can for example use recursion to drop a given number of elements.